# Wordpress alias problem

Tags: server, apache2, php, wordpress

I have configuration like this:

```
    Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
    Alias /blog/wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
    <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

In general I follow up this procedure [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/wordpress.html). Problem is in fact when I restart `apache2` I get message

```
"The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress at line 2 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias."
```

I had been added on `test.php` file on `/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content`. If I try `mydomain.com/blog/wp-content/test.php`, I got `error 404`. This means that in general I miss all plugins/themes static files.

What could be a fix for it?

Comment: If you solved your question, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the order of those Alias directives so the most specific one comes first:

```
Alias /blog/wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
```

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

> [...] the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear
>   in the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence.
>
> For this reason, when two or more of these directives apply to the
>   same sub-path, you must list the most specific path first in order for
>   all the directives to have an effect. For example, the following
>   configuration will work as expected:
>
> ```
> Alias /foo/bar /baz
> Alias /foo /gaq
> ```
>
> But if the above two directives were reversed in order, the /foo Alias
>   would always match before the /foo/bar Alias, so the latter directive
>   would be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
ServerName mydomain.com

ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
```

on the top of the conf file

Comment: -1, The `ServerAlias` directive is different from the `Alias` directive which the OP asking about

Comment: Dan, could u please explain?

Comment: In brief, [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ServerAlias) is used to allow *multiple URLs* for the same Virtual Host. While [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Alias) is used to allow a domain of a vritual host to access a directory outside its `DocumentRoot` path